# Getting an error "No module named 'internals' on running a python code on windows 8

Tags: python

I recently installed Python 3.4.1 on Windows 8 and  ran a code which gave me the error below. What steps should I follow to get rid of this error? Is there a link to install the mentioned module 'internals'?  Its basically referring to a line of code in the module NLTK which I have imported in my code.

**Error** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\user\project\abc\abc\xyz.py", line 9, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 91, in <module>
    from internals import config_java
ImportError: No module named 'internals'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*: NLTK 3.0.0b1 was released on July 11th, 2014 (two days after this question, go figure), adding support for Python 3.2 and up.

My original answer follows:

---

NLTK does [not yet support Python 3](http://www.nltk.org/install.html):

> NLTK requires Python versions 2.6-2.7.

You can download an alpha release at http://www.nltk.org/nltk3-alpha/

The import expects to find `internals` relative to the `ntlk` package, but Python 3 removed support for such (ambiguous) relative imports. Most likely, this will not be the only problem when running NLTK (other that the 3.0 alpha release) under Python 3.

Comment: According to the linked page, NLTK now supports Python3.2 or above.

Comment: @unutbu: well, wadajaknow, they released the alpha. :-)

Comment: @unutbu: the 3.0.0b1 release was made 2 days after this answer. Way to show me up! :-P